# Force document to render charts

Tags: vba, charts, ms-word

I'm having an issue in exporting a chart to an image as part of a Word VBA routine. During the course of the creation of the chart, it doesn't render on the screen until the entire procedure is complete. As a result, when the image is exported using

`doc.InlineShapes(1).Chart.Export FileName:=ThisDocument.Path & "\chart.bmp", FilterName:="BMP"`

the resolution is much lower than displayed on the screen once the procedure is complete. For clarity, the image below shows the original chart at the bottom and the exported image at the top.

I know this works when the chart is rendered on the screen because stepping through the code in break mode results in a higher resolution image being exported.

[image]

I've tried using the following methods to force the chart to render before exporting the image:

```
    doc.Activate
    doc.InlineShapes(1).Chart.Select
    Application.ScreenRefresh
    Sleep 10000
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll
```

Any and all suggestions are appreciated.